# Modifying font size of post title

Tags: css, frontend, jekyll, scss-lint

I want to lower down the post title's font size(of latest post) and continue displaying it in center for my jekyll based blog.

I tried modifying https://github.com/x0v/x0v.github.io/blob/master/_sass/atoms/_feature-title.scss like adding

```
font-size: 45px !important;
font-weight: 100 !important;
```

in `.feature-title__part`

but always ended up in making it even worse.

Can someone please suggest me what to do ?
Repo
https://github.com/x0v/x0v.github.io
URL:
https://imprashant.com/

I am noob at frontend stuff and I don't know anything about it. Though I keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked your URL and found that you need to add following to your code:

```
.feature-title {
   display: block;
}
.feature-title__part {
   font-size: 100px !important;
   text-align: center;
}
```

And hopefully this will give the result you want.